# Run telerik test with TFS BDT failed with Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0.dll can not find error

Tags: telerik

We are working on integrate telerik test case to tfs BDT.

While test controller run test case, it throws following error:

> Error adding test case [14621] to test run: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

We have installed Team Explorer for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 both on test controller and test agent.

We can run telerik test case from command line successfully on test agent.

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:"C:\Test-Code\Binaries\LoginTest.tstest"
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\Test Studio\Bin\ArtOfTest.Runner.exe"
>   test="C:\Test-Code\Binaries\LoginTest.tstest"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just now we have tried to restart test controller.

Now telerik test case can run and pass now.

So the issue can be resolved by following solution:

1. Install Team Explorer for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 both on test controller and test agent
2. Restart test controller and test agent